# Graph of $ax+f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Could someone help me in this problem: I have a nondecreasing function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb R$ (so we know how the graph will looks like). How can we graph the functions $ax$, $f(x)$, and $ax+f(x)$, ($a>0$) all on the same $xy-$coordinate; which one is above the other?

Comment: Well, you are asking which one is bigger $f(x)$ or $f(x)+ax$... What do you think? If to $f(x)$ you add a number, when does it become larger and when does it become less?

Comment: $ax+f(x)$ will be above $f(x)$ when $x>0$, equal to $f(x)$ when $x=0$, and below $f(x)$ when $x<0$. Without knowing more about $a$ and $f$, you can't say any more about which ones will be above or below the others.

Comment: I'm interested in $a=4$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

[image]

Note that

- The graph of $y=ax$ is  a straight line passing through  the
  origin with positive slope (for $a>0$).
- The graph of $g(x)=f(x)+ax$ can be obtained by "adding heights (or depths)" as
  indicated in the diagram.
- For $x>0$, the graph of $g(x)=f(x)+ax$ is above the graph of $y=f(x)$;
  because, in this case, to find the value of $g(x)$, you   add  a positive value, that of $ax$,
  to $f(x)$.
- For $x<0$, the graph of $g(x)=f(x)+ax$ is below the graph of $y=f(x)$;
  because, in this case,  to find the value of $g(x)$, you subtract  a positive value, that of $|ax|$,
  from $f(x)$.
- For $x=0$, we have $g(0)=f(0)+0=f(0)$.